# How not to wait for server side processing in php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, curl

I meet a big problem.
I have a PHP application (symfony), and an API only callable with curl.

The frontend (client side) sends many requests with ajax et the server side call the API.
And, when I abort the request Ajax the process in server side is not spotted.

Bellow the schema :

```
[Front] <=> request ajax 1 <=> [server side] <=> call Api in curl
[Front] <=> request ajax 2 <=> [server side] <=> call Api in curl
...
[Front] <=> request ajax n <=> [server side] <=> call Api in curl
```

The **request ajax n** will have to wait for all the previous answers before having an answer.

Problematic, I must keep the call with curl.

Question 1 - With API rest instead of server side, I will have the same problem?
Question 2 - Multithread PHP, Daemon, is a good solution for this problem ?

Comment: Do you use php-fpm? It must solve this problem at all. If it so but your requests still queuing you should better look for other thing that can block your code: [sessions files](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/08/session-locking-non-blocking-read-sessions-php/), [database locks](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=83), [file locks](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.flock.php) and of course locks on API side.

Comment: not to mention to add to @marv255 's comment the auto loading of files (auto_including) which symfony does, which is "slow" if you don't cache that, Query "huge" tables without indexes, use join without indexes.. But without clear benchmarks or clear timing where the critical points are in your Application we can't really help with optimisation.

Comment: @marv255 Yes I use already php-fpm.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The huge queries are in the cache, and all tables are indexed. 
The response time is 500 ms (in average for each request), but if I do 10 requests in the same time, the request 10 will have to wait for all the previous answers before having an answer.

Comment: does the same problem happen when you use `ab` (apache bench) ? Or some other comparable program.. Then you can maybe or maybe can not rule out server side performance problems.

Comment: @Greg I had same troubles with my site. All js queries was queuing on server side instead of running in parallel. Session was starting for each request and session file was blocking, so queries was processing one after another.

Comment: @RaymondNijland No, no problem with ab. And the performance server side is ok. already test

Comment: *"No, no problem with ab. And the performance server side is ok. already test "* ok fair enough, i had to ask to rule it out.  Then then it seams to be pure client side performance issues, which frameworks are you using client side and what browser?

Comment: Maybe it helps to give us the client side code as iam also tempted to also voteclose this question as *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*

Comment: @marv255 what were tests actions done with php-fpm?

Comment: Use guzzle with async requests? I'm only stabbing here because it's not 100% clear what you are trying to do or why for that matter.  http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#async-requests

Comment: @domagoj All request ajax are send with async yes.

Comment: @Greg I meant that you should use guzzle async from your server side to other API.

Comment: Have a look at the new Symfony 4 Mercure Component https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-gets-real-time-push-capabilities